# Can I take an intersection for polygons WITH A COMMON ID?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, intersection

I have a thiessan polygons for a bunch of cell towers, and need to cut them when they extend more than 12 miles from a cell tower. What I was thinking of doing is taking a buffer from each point, and taking an intersection of each tower's thiessan polygon and its buffer, but I don't know how to take an intersection BY A UNIQUE ID (the tower name). Can anyone help?

(I have ARCinfo 10, for what it's worth)

Thanks!

Nick

Comment: You could make a full intersection and delete all elements which don't have the same ID in the result.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you don't need to transfer any attributes from the buffered features to the thiessen polygons, so I suggest you use the Clip tool rather than the Intersect tool. This will simply remove all parts of the thiessen polygons that are not within 12 miles of a cell tower.

Edit: I just want to make it clear that this solution will work in this case because the cell tower locations were the input for both the thiessen polygons and the buffers. If different data sources were used, more complicated techniques would be required.